AWS CloudTrail with Dynamodb Stream
I'm trying to configure AWS CloudTrail to log inserts to a DynamoDB table.
I've created an Event Data Source which points to my table, with the following configuration, and it works fine:
[
  {
    "FieldSelectors": [
      {
        "Field": "eventCategory",
        "Equals": [
          "Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Field": "resources.type",
        "Equals": [
          "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Field": "resources.ARN",
        "Equals": [
          <table arn>
        ]
      },
      {
        "Field": "eventName",
        "Equals": [
          "PutItem"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

However, the events only include the table keys, rather than all values as I would prefer. Reading around the internet, it's suggested that this can be accomplished by instead having the data source track a stream from the DynamoDB table.
I enabled streaming on the table, with the stream view type set to NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES, and changed my data source config to the following:
[
  {
    "FieldSelectors": [
      {
        "Field": "eventCategory",
        "Equals": [
          "Data"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Field": "resources.type",
        "Equals": [
          "AWS::DynamoDB::Stream"
        ]
      },
      {
        "Field": "resources.ARN",
        "Equals": [
          <table stream arn>
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

With this, though, nothing ever appears in the log. Can anyone suggest why this might be the case?

Sounds like your stream doesn't have a StreamViewType enabled on your dynamo stream

It's does; it's set to NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES
